# putting a variable inside a button or image declaration

Tags: android

I am trying to do a data analysis And set image view visibility based on those data. Is that possible to put a variable inside a image view declaration so that I can use an array to analyse data and call the respective image view based on the variable for example
For(inti =0,i<20;i++)
Imageview(i).setvibility(gone)

This will prevent me from calling the image view over and over again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by creating a list of ImageViews.

```
List<ImageView> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewID);
list.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.anotherID);

for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
    ImageView view = list.get(i);
    view.visible(false);
}
```

Now you can iterate through your views.